# Why my login and register don't work when deployed (production) using .NET WebApi?

Tags: angular, production, internal-server-error

In development the login and register work but in production it is not, why is that?

in account controller (API) I have the below code to login the user. I am using this example because it is shorter to demonstrate.

```
[HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(loginReqDto loginReq)
    {
        var user = await uow.UserRepository.Authenticate(loginReq.UserName, loginReq.Password);

        ApiError apiError = new ApiError();

        if(user == null)
        {
            apiError.ErrorCode = Unauthorized().StatusCode;
            apiError.ErrorMessage = "Invalid userId or Password!";
            apiError.ErrorDetails = "This is appearing when user or password does not exist!";
            return Unauthorized(apiError);
        }

        var loginRes = new LoginResDto();
        loginRes.UserName = user.Username;
        loginRes.Token = CreateJWT(user);
        return Ok(loginRes);
    }
```

and in my frontend (angular):

```
onlogin(loginForm: NgForm){

console.log(loginForm.value);
this.authServive.authUser(loginForm.value).subscribe(      
  (response: any) => {
    console.log(response);
    const user = response;
    localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
    localStorage.setItem('userName', user.userName);
    this.alertify.success("You have loged-in successfully!");
    this.router.navigate(['/']);
  });
}
```

In Postman using development I am getting the code 200OK and generated the token. on the other hand, in production, I get internet server error code 500. Why?

Comment: And what exactly is the error 500? See your log files, it can be a missing database connection, a bug in your code and so on and so on ...

Comment: What does that `this.authService.authUser(...)` look like? Currently we can only see the receiving code, assuming that the request is valid - but it's clearly not, being a 500, so we're more concerned with what's going into the server before it gets anywhere near coming back to us.